# Get tuple with largest numeric element, and if a tie occurs, randomly pick one of the tied tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
a = [([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5), ([2, 5, 8], [3], 5.5), ([2, 5, 8], [9], 4.5)]
```

and I will like to get the tuple with the largest numeric element (non-list, for e.g. 5.5 in the case of `([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5)`, **and** if there is a tie, say for this example `([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5)` and `([2, 5, 8], [3], 5.5)`, one of these tied tuples will be randomly selected as the output.

My progress so far:

```
>>> import operator
>>> max(a, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
([3], [4, 7, 9], 5.5)
```

I am unsure as to how I can randomly pick one of the tied tuples at this point in time.. Some insight will be great!

**Remark:** To have a different choice every time the `choice(.)` function is run, do it with a seed and perform:

```
r = random.Random(500) # seed number is arbitrary
r.choice(...)
```

Comment: When you say "randomly pick one", do you mean "it doesn't matter which one you return" or do you *actually* mean that a random one should be picked? (i.e. did you mean "random" or "arbitrary"?)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I apologize if my question is not clear enough.. To clarify, "randomly pick one" implies that a random one of the ties shall be picked. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
m=max(a,key=lambda x: x[2])[2]
print(choice([i for i in a if i[2] == m]))
```

**Example:**

```
from random import choice
a = [([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5), ([2, 5, 8], [3], 5.5), ([2, 5, 8], [9], 4.5)]
m=max(a,key=lambda x: x[2])[2]
print(choice([i for i in a if i[2] == m]))
```

**Explanation:**

1. go trough the list, then take the ones that the third (2 in python indexing) then check it against the max element for the third index (second in python indexing) if it's the same, put it into the list, otherwise, no
2. use `random.choice`(in my case since i do `from .. import ..` use direct `choice`, to randomly pick an element

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic version that will work without relying on a specific index location:

```
from numbers import Number
from random import choice
max_subelement_value = None
for element in a:
    for subelement in element:
        if isinstance(subelement, Number) and (max_subelement_value is None or subelement > max_subelement_value):
            max_subelement_value = subelement
potential_results = [x for x in a if max_subelement_value in x]
choice(potential_results)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly too! :) I'll add a note in my question for the benefit of future readers, with regards to generating a different choice whenever the function is run.